# lambda: confused about parameter transmission

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda

I come from the SQL world, and I am a newbie to this.
I found on w3shools.com similar code:

```
def myfunc(n, m):
    return lambda a : a * n * m

mydoubler = myfunc(2, 6)
print(mydoubler(15))
```

I cannot figure out how the `a` parameter, which I asssume is "15" in the call, is made available to the lambda. I searched and I could not find a description of the logical and programmatic paradigm.

Answer (score 0):

lambda function is an anonymous function, this mean that a lambda expression is a function by itself but is inline. here, you created a function that will return a lambda expression that calculates the products of a and n and m so the returned value will be that. we know that when we return a function, we can store what we returned in a variable, in our case, we returned a lambda function so you need to enter the a value. if it is not clear, ask me

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Lambda function is a function, but without a name. The only difference is, ho definition looks like.
Your code snipped could be translated to:

```
def myfunc(n, m):

    def some_func(a):
        return a * n * m

    return some_func

mydoubler = myfunc(2, 6)
print(mydoubler(15))
```

And the result would be the same.
From the official Python docs [Lambda Expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions):

> Like nested function definitions, lambda functions can reference variables from the containing scope

Because of that, values of `n` and `m` are available for the function. Value of `a` is passed when you are executing `mydoubler`.

Answer (score 0):

this is a detailed answer:

first of all, you created the function myfunc that requires 2 arguments "n" and "m". then you will return a lambda function that takes an argument "a" and returns the product of "a","n" and "m". then you declared a variable mydoubler whose value is the returned value of myfunc which is that lambda. imagine that mydoubler = lambda a: a * 2 * 6. and finally you printed the returned value of mydoubler which is a function and the argument a is 15. if you didnt understand the lambda format for mydoubler, here is it but as a normal function:
def mydoubler(a):
return a * 2 * 6
dont forget, 2 is the value of n and 6 is the value of m

Comment: Thanks for answering that. I am not sure I understand your answer. if the code I provided is same as "def mydoubler(a): return a * 2 * 6" (or as I understand, "return a * m * n"), and only "a" is passed as a parameter, then how are "m" and "n" passed into mydoubler? This seems to exchange one quandary for another one. Thanks.

Comment: @IKnowSomeThings look, you already passed the values for n and m when assigning mydoubler. you wrote mydoubler = myfunc(2,6) = lambda a: a * 2 * 6. so mydoubler s data type is a function which requires an argument "a".

Comment: @IKnowSomeThings, in other words, mydoubler is the equivalent of this function:      def mydoubler(a):                                                                                                                          ....return a * 2 * 6

Comment: @IKnowSomeThings if you need another explanation, just ask me :)